# Загрузка файла WebKit Qt

Tags: webkit, qt

Здравствуйте. Нужно сделать что-то типа браузера (специфического). Взял пример: `fancybrowser - WebKit` в `QWebView`. Может кто подскажет, а еще лучше пример приведет - как научить его скачивать файлы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest)

> The QNetworkAccessManager class allows the application to send network requests and receive replies

[QWebPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346219/how-to-download-files-from-qwebview)

> QWebView has a 'QWebPage' member which you can access it's pointer with webView.page() . This is where you should look. QWebPage has two signals: downloadRequested(..) and unsupportedContent(..). I believe dowloadRequest is only emitted when user right clicks a link and selects 'Save Link' and unsupportedContent is emitted when target URL cannot be shown (not an html/text).
>
> But for unsupportedContent to be emitted, you should set forwardUnsupportedContent to True with function webPage.setForwardUnsupportedContent(true). Here is a minimal example I have created: